# Filtering by ManyToMany field length: values_list() returns, but the filtering result is empty

Tags: python, sql, django

I have such a model in `Django`:

```
class VariantTag():                                                                                           
    saved_variants = models.ManyToManyField('SavedVariant')                                                                
    variant_tag_type = models.ForeignKey('VariantTagType', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then, I am trying to get the `VariantTag` models with `saved_variants` field of length `2` which contain at least one of the id from the `variant_ids` `pk` list:

```
het_tags = (VariantTag.objects.annotate(variant_len=Count('saved_variants'))) \                                     
            .filter(saved_variants__in=variant_ids, variant_len=2)                                                      
logger.info(het_tags.all())                                                                                         
het_variant_ids = het_tags.values_list('saved_variants', flat=True)                                               
logger.info('******* het_variant_ids: {}'.format(het_variant_ids))
```

`Logger` output that I get is the following:

```
<QuerySet []>
******* het_variant_ids: <QuerySet [150, 149]>
```

Where `150` and `149` are correct ids that I am looking for. However, I need to get full `QuerySet` objects, how to get them? Why is it not working?

> Update

Both query conditions are working on their own separately, but applied together they give an empty result. According to the data I have in the models that should not happen.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why but restructuring of the query to do the filtering first for ids, then annotation, and only then filtering by length of `ManyToMany` field worked out:

```
het_tags = (VariantTag.objects.filter(saved_variants__in=variant_ids)
                              .annotate(variant_len=Count('saved_variants')))
                              .filter(variant_len=2)
```

If you have any idea of why this works, please, post another answer.